# Blender 2.8 Merge by distance work. It does't remove doubles

Tags: vertices

I stacked two cubes one on top of another. Went in Edit mode and x ray view. Selected all the joint vertices. Then tried merge by distance. Merge distance 0.01m and Merge distance 0.0001m. The function only works if I go merge distance 2m then of course I dont get the results I won't. With is remove double vertices.

Comment: Blender 2.8 Merge by distance *doesn't work

Comment: Please use the edit link below your post to edit the title instead of a comment. I would also recommend to consider using a descriptive title in form of a clearly formed question instead of a few false statements. For example: "How can I use Merge by Distance to remove doubles in Blender 2.80?" This might help you get good answers faster.

Comment: Works for me in version 2.8 from the 23rd of June.  Are your two cubes part of the same mesh?  Even though 2.8 allows switching to Edit mode with multiple objects selected, it can't merge vertexes from different meshes.  You can still join them to one mesh with ctrl-J by default (blender keymap), if this is the problem you're having.